# How to parse JSON when the object contains an array of other objects?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I've been trying to parse a JSON in Swift where the object contains an array of other objects. Like this:

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "name": "Life Sciences",
      "id": "4343435",

      "children" : [
        {
          "name": "name1",
          "id" : "5344444",
        },

        {
          "name": "name2",
          "id" : "5134343",
        },
      .....
```

I need to be able to access the name and id properties, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong with my code below. My JSON file contains all the necessary data, yet, I keep getting the ***"unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping optional"*** error when I try to loop over the children array. Before that line the JSON is parsed correctly and works.

```
let loadURL = "https:// ....."
var people = [Person]()

func getPersonData() {
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: loadURL)!)
    let urlSession = URLSession.shared
    let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        // Parse JSON data
        if let data = data {
            self.people = self.parseJsonData(data)
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation{() -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}

func parseJsonData(_ data: Data) -> [Person] {
    var people = [Person]()

    do {
        let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

        // Parse JSON data
        let jsonPeople = jsonResult?["people"] as! [AnyObject]
        for jsonPerson in jsonPeople {
            let person = Person()
            person.name = jsonPerson["name"] as! String
            person.id = jsonPerson["id"] as! String

            //ERROR//: "unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping optional..."
            let jsonChildren = jsonResult?["children"] as! [AnyObject]
            for jsonChild in jsonChildren {
                let child = Child()
                child.name = jsonEntrance["name"] as! String
                child.age = jsonEntrance["age"] as! Int

                person.children.append(child)
            }

            people.append(person)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return people
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made an error here:

```
let jsonChildren = jsonResult?["children"] as! [AnyObject]
```

Should be:

```
let jsonChildren = jsonPerson["children"] as! [AnyObject]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your JSON data on some point has no "children" value, try to avoid force casting to [AnyObject]. You may try to change it in this way:

```
if let result = jsonResult, let jsonChildren = result["children"] as? [AnyObject] {
      for jsonChild in jsonChildren {
           let child = Child()
           child.name = jsonEntrance["name"] as! String
           child.age = jsonEntrance["age"] as! Int

           person.children.append(child)
      }
}
```

Also, you may try use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) which will help you to do your json data processing much more easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, but the problem is that you are search for wrong dictionary. Your 'jsonResult' key doesn't have a key for 'children'. But your 'jsonPerson' object has a 'children' key. Replace your below line of code -

```html
let jsonChildren = jsonResult?["children"] as! [AnyObject]
```

Replace this line with this one -

```html
            let jsonChildren = jsonPerson?["children"] as! [AnyObject]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the JSON does not represent the actual JSON in the code.

Second of all, **never ever** use `NSDictionary` in Swift unless you have no choice.

Third of all, cast an JSON array containing dictionaries  to `[[String:Any]]`, never to `[Any(Object)]`

Fourth of all, a JSON dictionary in Swift 3 is `[String:Any]`

Fifth of all, use optional bindings to avoid runtime errors (crashes)

```
func parseJsonData(_ data: Data) -> [Person] {
  var people = [Person]()

  do {
    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String:Any]

    // Parse JSON data
    if let jsonPeople = jsonResult["people"] as? [[String:Any]] {
      for jsonPerson in jsonPeople {
        let person = Person()
        person.name = jsonPerson["name"] as! String
        person.id = jsonPerson["id"] as! String

        // children is a key of a person not of the root object !
        if let jsonChildren = jsonPerson["children"] as? [[String:Any]] {
          for jsonChild in jsonChildren {
            let child = Child()
            child.name = jsonChild["name"] as! String
            child.age = jsonChild["age"] as! Int

            person.children.append(child)
          }
        }

        people.append(person)
      }
    }
  } catch {
    print(error)
  }
  return people
}
```

PS: You will get another error *undefined identifier* because `jsonEntrance` in the child loop in your code does not exist and `children` is a key of `people` not of the root object.